# Why mobile view does not match desktop view?

Tags: html, mobile, google-chrome-devtools

I have an HTML document, let say this:

```html
<p>
    lorem ipsum
</p>
```

In my computer it looks like this:
 [image: desktop]

But, from a mobile its:
[image: mobile]

If you click the images you'll see that in the mobile view it looks reduced. I'm usign the chrome-dev-tools to simulate mobile view (but in my phone its the same) and inspecting the element I see that the `html` content has 980 X 1742 px, when it should have 360 X 640 px.
[image: dev-tools]

That's from my computer using chrome-dev-tools. Can someone tell my how can I fix this, or at least what am I doing wrong? Or that's how it's suppose to be from a mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

Try to add this.

Comment: I did it and it worked! Thanks. Can you explain why it worked plz?

Comment: @Theia Oh.. I tried to explain but I can't ... Cause I'm not good at English. I can only suggest you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag